# What is a maximum number of arguments in a Python function?

Tags: python, function, arguments, language-features, limit

It's somewhat common knowledge that Python functions can have a maximum of 256 arguments.  What I'm curious to know is if this limit applies to `*args` and `**kwargs` when they're unrolled in the following manner:

```
items = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def do_something(*items):
    pass
```

I ask because, hypothetically, there might be cases where a list larger than 256 items gets unrolled as a set of `*args` or `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Python 3.7 and newer, there is no limit. This is the result of work done in [issue #27213](https://bugs.python.org/issue27213) and [issue #12844](https://bugs.python.org/issue12844); #27213 reworked the `CALL_FUNCTION*` family of opcodes for performance and simplicity (part of 3.6), freeing up the opcode argument to only encode a single argument count, and #12844 removed the compile-time check that prevented code with more arguments from being compiled.

So as of 3.7, with the [`EXTENDED_ARG()` opcode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-EXTENDED_ARG), there is now *no limit at all* on how many arguments you can pass in using explicit arguments, save how many can be fitted onto the stack (so bound now by your memory):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=0, releaselevel='alpha', serial=2)
>>> def f(*args, **kwargs): pass
...
>>> exec("f({})".format(', '.join(map(str, range(256)))))
>>> exec("f({})".format(', '.join(map(str, range(2 ** 16)))))
```

Do note that lists, tuples and dictionaries are limited to [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) elements, so if the called function uses `*args` and/or `**kwargs` catch-all parameters then those *are* limited.

For the `*args` and `**kwargs` call syntax (expanding arguments) there are no limits other than the same `sys.maxint` size limits on Python standard types.

In versions before Python 3.7, CPython has a limit of 255 explicitly passed arguments in a call:

```
>>> def f(*args, **kwargs): pass
...
>>> exec("f({})".format(', '.join(map(str, range(256)))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: more than 255 arguments
```

This limitation is in place because until Python 3.5, the [`CALL_FUNCTION` opcode](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION) overloaded the opcode argument to encode both the number of positional and keyword arguments on the stack, each encoded in a single byte.

Answer (score 25):

In Python 3.6 and before, the limit is due to how the compiled bytecode treats calling a function with position arguments and/or keyword arguments.

The bytecode op of concern is [`CALL_FUNCTION`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION) which carries an `op_arg` that is 4 bytes in length, but on the two least significant bytes are used. Of those, the most significant byte represent the number of keyword arguments on the stack and the least significant byte the number of positional arguments on the stack. Therefore, you can have at most `0xFF == 255` keyword arguments or `0xFF == 255` positional arguments.

This limit does not apply to `*args` and `**kwargs` because calls with that grammar use the bytecode ops [`CALL_FUNCTION_VAR`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION_VAR), [`CALL_FUNCTION_KW`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION_KW), and [`CALL_FUNCTION_VAR_KW`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION_VAR_KW) depending on the signature. For these opcodes, the stack consists of an iterable for the `*args` and a `dict` for the `**kwargs`. These items get passed directly to the receiver which unrolls them as needed.

Comment: Is this a CPython implementation restriction, or is it part of Python itself?

Comment: It's an implementation detail of the CPython bytecode.

Comment: … indeed. The limitation will be released with CPython 3.7.

Answer (score 24):

WFM

```
>>> fstr = 'def f(%s): pass' % (', '.join(['arg%d' % i for i in range(5000)]))
>>> exec(fstr)
>>> f
<function f at 0x829bae4>
```

**Update:** as Brian noticed, the limit is on the calling side:

```
>>> exec 'f(' + ','.join(str(i) for i in range(5000)) + ')'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>
    exec 'f(' + ','.join(str(i) for i in range(5000)) + ')'
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: more than 255 arguments (<string>, line 1)
```

on the other hand this works:

```
>>> f(*range(5000))
>>>
```

**Conclusion:** no, it does not apply to unrolled arguments.

Comment: It looks like the limit is on the calling side.  Try exec 'f(' + ','.join(str(i) for i in range(5000)) + ')'

Comment: @Stefan: *Works For Me*

Comment: This answer is outdated. The 255 arg limit was removed in Python 3.7

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a restriction in compiling the source, so will probably exist only for arguments being passed directly, not in *args or **kwargs.

The relevant code can be found in [ast.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/ast.c?view=markup):

```
if (nargs + nkeywords + ngens > 255) {
  ast_error(n, "more than 255 arguments");
  return NULL;
}
```

But note that this is in ast_for_call, and so only applys to the calling side. ie `f(a,b,c,d,e...)`, rather than the definition, though it will count both positional `(a,b,c,d)` and `keyword (a=1, b=2, c=3)` style parameters .  Actual `*args` and `**kwargs` parameters look like they should only count as one argument for these purposes on the calling side.

Comment: Outdated answer. The link is broken and that check doesn't happen starting with Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

for **kwargs, If I remember well, this is a dictionary. It therefore has about no limits.

for *args, I am not so sure, but I think it is a tuple or a list, so it also has about no limits.

By no limits, I mean except maybe the memory limit.

Answer (score -1):

I tried for a list of 4000 items, and it worked. So I'm guessing it will work for larger values as well.