# How do I convert a derived recursive data type to a base data type?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class called nesteddict derived from collections.defaultdict that hold a nested set of dictionaries:

```
import collections

class nesteddict(collections.defaultdict):
    """Nested dictionary structure.

    Based on Stack Overflow question 635483
    """
    def __init__(self):
        collections.defaultdict.__init__(self, nesteddict)
        self.locked = False
```

I would like to be able to perform an operation an instance that converts all of the nesteddict objects to python-native dict objects.

One way to do this is to have a method:

```
def todict(self):
    for (key,val) in self.iteritems():
        if isinstance(val,nesteddict):
            val.todict()
            self[key] = dict(val)
    self = dict(self)
```

This is successful at replacing all the inner mapping objects with dict types, but the last statement in the method is obviously not going to work.

Here is an example:

```
In [93]: a = pyutils.nesteddict()

In [94]: a[1][1] = 'a'

In [95]: a[1][2] = 'b'

In [96]: a[2][1] = 'c'

In [97]: a[2][2] = 'd'

In [98]: print a
defaultdict(<class 'pyutils.nesteddict'>, {1: defaultdict(<class 'pyutils.nesteddict'>, {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}), 2: defaultdict(<class 'pyutils.nesteddict'>, {1: 'c', 2: 'd'})})

In [99]: a.todict()

In [100]: print a
defaultdict(<class 'pyutils.nesteddict'>, {1: {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}, 2: {1: 'c', 2: 'd'}})
```

Is there a way to do this in python?  Have a method that converts its object to another type?  If not, what is a good alternative to this.  Note that the datatype in practice may be large, so it would be preferable not to just make a copy and then return it.

Thanks!
Uri

Comment: "I would like to be able to perform an operation an instance that converts all of the nesteddict objects to python-native dict objects.
"  Why?  It already is a `dict` object.  You don't need to convert anything.  It's a subclass of `defaultdict` which means it **is** a `dict`.

Comment: After loading data into it, I want to "lock" it.  One way to implement this is so make the default_factory method a function that raises a KeyError, which seems to work fine.  However, I was having trouble serializing this class using cPickle.  Conversion to a pure dict will allow easy serialization (including with json), and will effectively lock the dictionary in a similar fashion.

Comment: @S.Lott pickle is a common reason to want a conversion to pure dictionaries: otherwise, to unpickle it, you need to bring the definition of the specialized dict, eg. `infinite_defaultdict = lambda: defaultdict(infinite_defaultdict)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it as a free function, and while you're at it, consider a more functional style approach:

```
def undefaulted(x):
  return dict(
    (k, undefaulted(v))
    for (k, v) in x.iteritems()
  ) if isinstance(x, nesteddict) else x

a = undefaulted(a)
```

Comment: For future visitors: the other answer using a dict comprehension is indeed superior to using `dict()`. In addition to @Jamie's claim, it's also faster *and* more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

I've just faced this problem myself using nested defaultdicts. My solution:

```
def dictify(d):
    return {k:dictify(v) for k,v in d.items()} if \
        isinstance(d,nesteddict) else d
```

It is better to use {} rather than dict() because calling the 
constructor of dict() limits the number of keyword arguments 
to 255.  See:   [What is a maximum number of arguments in a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714475/what-is-a-maximum-number-of-arguments-in-a-python-function)

Answer (score 1):

`dict(a)` will give you a default dict from any object that derives from `defaultdict`.  That is, assuming you havn't overridden the required special methods.

Comment: Yes, but it won't descend recursively into the nested dictionaries.  It will only convert the top-level nesteddict object to a dict.

Comment: yah.. completely forgot about the recursive part of the request.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice in your code, is that you're modifying (or trying to) the `self` variable. That variable is just pointing at the current instance of your class. If you reassign it, you're just pointing it at another value, but the previous value pointed by `self` remains unchanged. This is just how Python works.

So, what you should to is just return the result of the transformation in your method... something like this:

```
def anothertodict(self):
    stuff = dict(self)
    for (key,val) in stuff.iteritems():
        if isinstance(val,nesteddict):
            stuff[key] = val.anothertodict()
    return stuff
```

That way, if you do a: `print a.anothertodict()` you'll get what you're expecting to get.

*PS: Why do you need to convert from defaultdict to dict?*