# Override the {...} notation so i get an OrderedDict() instead of a dict()?

Tags: python, dictionary, overriding, built-in, ordereddictionary

> Update: dicts retaining insertion order is guaranteed for Python 3.7+

I want to use a .py file like a config file.
So using the `{...}` notation I can create a dictionary using strings as keys but the definition order is lost in a standard python dictionary.

My question: is it possible to override the `{...}` notation so that I get an `OrderedDict()` instead of a `dict()`?

I was hoping that simply overriding dict constructor with OrderedDict (`dict = OrderedDict`) would work, but it doesn't.

Eg:

```
dict = OrderedDict
dictname = {
   'B key': 'value1',
   'A key': 'value2',
   'C key': 'value3'
   }

print dictname.items()
```

Output:

```
[('B key', 'value1'), ('A key', 'value2'), ('C key', 'value3')]
```

Comment: I assume that the Output mentioned here is what you would like - not what happens ?

Comment: FYI to people stumbling on this 5 year old question in 2016: as of python 3.6 all `dict`s retain insertion order, so going forward none of these hacks will be needed.

Comment: @NickSweeting https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation says "The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon".

Comment: @Samuel Santana the way I read the rest of the sentence that you quoted the start of suggests that this new ordering-preservation is the long term desired semantics for the language, without committing to it, right now.

Comment: As of 3.7, those semantics _can_ be relied upon

Comment: @NickSweeting: As noted, it's a language guarantee as of 3.7 (only an implementation detail in 3.6). These hacks might still be useful to get `OrderedDict`'s unique methods though; `popitem`'s ability to pop in FIFO mode isn't available on `dict`, and `move_to_end` isn't available at all (you can simulate `last=True` mode with `mydict[key] = mydict.pop(key)`, but it's slightly more expensive, and `last=False` mode is unavailable). 3.6-3.7 also lack the ability to iterate `dict` & its views in reverse, though [3.8 is (probably) adding that ability](https://bugs.python.org/issue33462).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Here's a hack that almost gives you the syntax you want:

```
class _OrderedDictMaker(object):
    def __getitem__(self, keys):
        if not isinstance(keys, tuple):
            keys = (keys,)
        assert all(isinstance(key, slice) for key in keys)

        return OrderedDict([(k.start, k.stop) for k in keys])

ordereddict = _OrderedDictMaker()
```

```
from nastyhacks import ordereddict

menu = ordereddict[
   "about" : "about",
   "login" : "login",
   'signup': "signup"
]
```

**Edit:** Someone else discovered this independently, and has published the [`odictliteral`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/odictliteral/) package on PyPI that provides a slightly more thorough implementation - **use that package instead**

Comment: shudder - i can see why you call that a hack - please - don't use that in production

Comment: This is genius. Evil genius.

Comment: @RégisB.: This post has got a lot of attention today - was it linked to from elsewhere?

Comment: @Eric I came here from reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/4xyfh7/one_of_the_neatest_python_tricks_ive_ever_seen/?st=irxxcanz&sh=a6b172af

Comment: TIL we can use strings with slice object.

Comment: To help decipher how this works, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936863/python-implementing-slicing-in-getitem

Comment: @Eric it doesn't work if one key: menu = ordereddict["about" : "about"]; but it seems easy to fix it.

Comment: @TatianaP: Nice catch, fixed. But use the pypi version not mine anyway!

Answer (score 40):

To literally get what you are asking for, you have to fiddle with the syntax tree of your file.  I don't think it is advisable to do so, but I couldn't resist the temptation to try.  So here we go.

First, we create a module with a function `my_execfile()` that works like the built-in `execfile()`, except that all occurrences of dictionary displays, e.g. `{3: 4, "a": 2}` are replaced by explicit calls to the `dict()` constructor, e.g. `dict([(3, 4), ('a', 2)])`.  (Of course we could directly replace them by calls to `collections.OrderedDict()`, but we don't want to be too intrusive.)  Here's the code:

```
import ast

class DictDisplayTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Dict(self, node):
        self.generic_visit(node)
        list_node = ast.List(
            [ast.copy_location(ast.Tuple(list(x), ast.Load()), x[0])
             for x in zip(node.keys, node.values)],
            ast.Load())
        name_node = ast.Name("dict", ast.Load())
        new_node = ast.Call(ast.copy_location(name_node, node),
                            [ast.copy_location(list_node, node)],
                            [], None, None)
        return ast.copy_location(new_node, node)

def my_execfile(filename, globals=None, locals=None):
    if globals is None:
        globals = {}
    if locals is None:
        locals = globals
    node = ast.parse(open(filename).read())
    transformed = DictDisplayTransformer().visit(node)
    exec compile(transformed, filename, "exec") in globals, locals
```

With this modification in place, we *can* modify the behaviour of dictionary displays by overwriting `dict`.  Here is an example:

```
# test.py
from collections import OrderedDict
print {3: 4, "a": 2}
dict = OrderedDict
print {3: 4, "a": 2}
```

Now we can run this file using `my_execfile("test.py")`, yielding the output

```
{'a': 2, 3: 4}
OrderedDict([(3, 4), ('a', 2)])
```

Note that for simplicity, the above code doesn't touch dictionary comprehensions, which should be transformed to generator expressions passed to the `dict()` constructor.  You'd need to add a `visit_DictComp()` method to the `DictDisplayTransformer` class.  Given the above example code, this should be straight-forward.

Again, I don't recommend this kind of messing around with the language semantics.  Did you have a look into the `ConfigParser` module?

Comment: Yes I will use ConfigParser...but your solution is illuminating. Thank you very much.

Comment: @fdb - before you think of changing the language semantics - think about the principle 'Explicit is better than implicit' - if you try to override '{}' or hide to avoid having to type 'OrderedDict' - you will end up making your code far more difficult to read for others - of for yourself 6 months down the line. Just type 'OrderedDict' - it is understood, and does what you want - more typing, but improved readability.

Answer (score 13):

`OrderedDict` is not "standard python syntax", however, an ordered set of key-value pairs (in standard python syntax) is simply:

```
[('key1 name', 'value1'), ('key2 name', 'value2'), ('key3 name', 'value3')]
```

To explicitly get an `OrderedDict`:

```
OrderedDict([('key1 name', 'value1'), ('key2 name', 'value2'), ('key3 name', 'value3')])
```

Another alternative, is to sort `dictname.items()`, if that's all you need:

```
sorted(dictname.items())
```

Comment: my question isn't if OrderedDict is "standard python syntax" but if is possible to override the {...} notation

Comment: @fdb: In Python `{}` creates a `dict` object, which is unordered by definition.  You can of course define your own language with `{}` denoting an orderd dictionary.  You can even write a small wrapper that translates your new language to Python.  Is this what you actually want?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: yes! but was hoping that simply overriding dict constructor with OrderedDict (dict = OrderedDict) would work.

Comment: @fdb: That only works if you make your dictionary by calling `dict()`

Comment: `sorted(dictname.items())` gives the items in ascending lexical order of the keys. `OrderedDict` ordering is by insertion order, not by key lexical order. You may be thinking of `SortedDict` (which does not currently exist).

Comment: before you think of changing the language semantics - think about the principle 'Explicit is better than implicit' - if you try to override '{}' or hide to avoid having to type 'OrderedDict' - you will end up making your code far more difficult to read for others - of for yourself 6 months down the line. Just type 'OrderedDict' - it is understood, and does what you want - more typing, but improved readability.

Answer (score 6):

As of python 3.6, [all dictionaries will be *ordered* by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-cpython-3-6).

Insertion order is always preserved in the new `dict` implementation:

```
>>>x = {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3 }
>>>list(x.keys())
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

As of python 3.6 `**kwargs` order [[PEP468]](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep468) and class attribute order [[PEP520](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep520)] are preserved.  The new [compact, ordered dictionary implementation](https://morepypy.blogspot.ca/2015/01/faster-more-memory-efficient-and-more.html) is used to implement the ordering for both of these.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with what https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation says: "The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon". Still, I found the information interesting, so here's an upvote!

Comment: Update: Insert order being preserved is now standard in 3.7 and can be relied upon.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for is impossible, but if a config file in [JSON](http://json.org/example.html) syntax is sufficient you can do something similar with the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders):

```
>>> import json, collections
>>> d = json.JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook = collections.OrderedDict)
>>> d.decode('{"a":5,"b":6}')
OrderedDict([(u'a', 5), (u'b', 6)])
```

Comment: "Impossible" might be a bit too strong a word -- see my answer.

Comment: @Sven: Yes, I totally enjoyed your answer! :) I think I will let my wording stand, though. Please adjust your understanding of "impossible" in this context to match reality ;)

Comment: **json.loads** and **json.load** have been also updated since Python 3.1 with support for object_pairs_hook https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.load

Answer (score 5):

The one solution I found is to patch python itself, making the `dict` object remember the order of insertion.

This then works for all kind of syntaxes:

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3 }
y = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

etc.

I have taken the `ordereddict` C implementation from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.ordereddict/ and merged back into the main python code.

If you do not mind re-building the python interpreter, here is a patch for Python 2.7.8:
https://github.com/fwyzard/cpython/compare/2.7.8...ordereddict-2.7.8.diff
.A

Comment: As of 2016/12, the Pypy implementation will become the standard python `dict` implementation, nice job predicting this 2 years in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is a way to get easy-to-use initialization syntax  - consider creating a subclass of OrderedDict and adding operators to it that update the dict, for example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class OrderedMap(OrderedDict):
    def __add__(self,other):
        self.update(other)
        return self

d = OrderedMap()+{1:2}+{4:3}+{"key":"value"}
```

d will be- OrderedMap([(1, 2), (4, 3), ('key','value')])

---

Another possible syntactic-sugar example using the slicing syntax:

```
class OrderedMap(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            self[index.start] = index.stop 
            return self
        else:
            return OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, index)

d = OrderedMap()[1:2][6:4][4:7]["a":"H"]
```

Comment: Note: Both of these violate the expectations of their operators in extreme ways. Both `__add__` and `__getitem__` are intended to be non-mutating, and slicing support is expected to be an aggregate form of indexing support, not a completely unrelated behavior. Violating those expectations is *asking* for maintainability nightmare. The `slice` hack is much better used to achieve the result given in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37259917/364696), where it's a factory object that makes a normal `OrderedDict`, not an `OrderedDict` replacement with ongoing weird behaviors.