# Override built-in classes, in particular, dictionary class

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, overriding, built-in-types

I've never really liked the way the dictionary class is converted into a string so I wrote a subclass which overrides the `__repr__` method (this method uses tabs to representing the level of nesting in the dictionary, mostly because I have some dictionaries which can be very big and end up `myDic['a']['b']['c']['d'] = someObject`).

It works fine, but it doesn't allow me to use the `{}` syntax to make my dictionaries.

Is it possible to override the dict class such that I can use the `{}` syntax to make my own custom dictionaries?

I am using python 2.6/2.7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is possible to override the {...} notation so i get an OrderedDict() instead of a dict()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878933/is-possible-to-override-the-notation-so-i-get-an-ordereddict-instead-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the `{}` syntax. You have to explicitly construct your variables using the class name.

If you just want it printed more nicely, would using [`pprint.pprint`](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) suffice?

Comment: just playing with pprint now, looks promising. I think what I had was basically pprint(myDict, width=1)