# Override builtin list syntax in python

Tags: python

I wanted to try and replace python's mutable datastructures with immutable ones (similar to clojure).

Subclassing the builtin list class works and you can override `__builtin__.list` but I haven't found any way of changing what builtin syntax refers to

```
__builtin__.list = ImmutableListClass

my_list = [1, 2, 3]
print type(my_list)

>>> <type 'list'>
```

Is there any way to change this behavior or is it hardcoded in the interpreter?

*Disclaimer: I'm aware this should never be done in a serious project and it's purely for my own entertainment.*

Comment: For entertainment purpose you can look up for `tuples` in python :), They are immutable by default  and you won't need to override anything :P

Comment: You could use a colections.UserList and override the methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant since these module are written in C, and hence have `.so` extensions. You can however try using forbidden fruit:

http://clarete.li/forbiddenfruit/

Comment: I accept this answer, because it seems that the only possibility is to use forbidden fruit to modify (instead of replace) the existing `list` type which is used by the `[1, 2, 3]` syntax.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7880276/4022180) does something similar, albeit with dicts, so I imagine that it could be adapted. However, I'm far too frightened to try.