# How to use [] with a custom __builtin__ list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to understand how `__builtin__` works in Python. My code is as follows:

```
import __builtin__

class MyList(list):
    pass

__builtin__.list = MyList

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = list([1,2,3,4,5])

print 'A: ', type(a)
print 'B: ', type(b)
```

When I print the types of both of the lists, I get:

```
A:  <type 'list'>
B:  <class '__main__.MyList'>
```

Why aren't both lists of type `MyList` and how can I achieve that `[]` syntax would also be of type `MyList`?

Comment: Because `[]` is a literal.

Comment: @martineau I read the question too quickly and misunderstood. The OP is asking about overriding literal syntax.

Comment: So, you could hack the syntax tree to achieve this, maybe, but it sounds like a lot of effort for very little reward.

Comment: So, see for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878933/override-the-notation-so-i-get-an-ordereddict-instead-of-a-dict/37259917

Comment: ah ok so literals can't be overwritten?

Comment: See the link I posted previously.

Comment: Assigning to `__builtin__` variables will never affect the Python language internals the way you're hoping. The `__builtin__` module is simply the standard fallback for global variable lookup, and assignments to `__builtin__` variables can only affect global variable lookup. Evaluating literals like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` involves no global variable lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check how `[]` is handled by CPython interprerter with `dis` module, you would see that it spawns `BUILD_LIST` instruction:

```
>>> def x():
...     x = [1,2]
... 
>>> dis.dis(x)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 BUILD_LIST               2
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

The corresponding instruction triggers direct call to C function `PyList_New` (it is handled in ceval.c):

```
2202        case BUILD_LIST:
2203            x =  PyList_New(oparg);
```

I think that if CPython would search `list` constructor in `__builtin__` pseudo-module each time `[]` are used in source, it would be much slower, so this behavior can be considered an optimization.

So what you asking is not achievable in vanilla CPython.