# How do I tell dict() in Python 2 to use unicode instead of byte string?

Tags: python, unicode, dictionary, python-2.x

Here is an example:

```
d = dict(a = 2)
print d
{'a': 2}
```

How can I tell `dict()` constructor to use Unicode instead without writing the string literal expliclity like `u'a'`? I am loading a dictionary from a `json` module which defaults to use unicode. I want to make use of unicode from now on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a dict with Unicode keys, use Unicode strings when constructing the dict:

```
>>> d = {u'a': 2}
>>> d
{u'a': 2}
```

Dicts created from keyword arguments always have string keys. If you want those to be Unicode (as well as all other strings), switch to Python 3.

Comment: Yes. But if I want to use a instead of using a string literal explicit?

Comment: @CppLearner: You cannot with `dict()`. That's using Python keywords, which are always (byte) strings.

Comment: Ah thanks. Just saw the edit and Ignacio's answer. So only Python 3 is capable of doing this by default using keyword argument in the constructor.

Comment: @CppLearner Yes, that's what the answer says.

Answer (score 5):

Keyword arguments in 2.x can only use ASCII characters, which means bytestrings. Either use a dict literal, or use one of the constructors that allows specifying the full type.

```
>>> dict(((u'a', 2),))
{u'a': 2}
```

Comment: Right at the moment I don't have a 3.x handy with me. So in 3.x using keyword argument the default is unicode or not?

Comment: @CppLearner: In 3.x, Unicode is the default type for strings period, and identifiers can use any Unicode letter followed by any number of Unicode letters or numbers.
`3>> dict(a=2, あ=3)`
`{'あ': 3, 'a': 2}`