# Why use "dict()" at all in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider these two statements, which serve the same purpose:

```
tel = {'sape': 4139, 'jack': 4098}
```

and

```
tel = dict([('sape', 4139), ('jack', 4098)])
```

Why use "dict()" at all?

I am sure there is a reason, i just want to know it.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610606/dict-literal-vs-dict-constructor-any-preferred) QA will answer your question. Basically the `dict()` call is more flexible and can do a few things that the `{}` can't do. Like use kwargs to create a dict, create a dict from a list directly, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the existence of `dict(...)` is that all classes need to have a constructor. Furthermore, it may be helpful if the constructor is able to take in data in a different format.

In your example use case, there is no benefit in using `dict`, because you can control the format the data is in. But consider if you have the data already as pairs in a list, the `dict` constructor may be useful. This can happen e.g. when reading lines from a file.

Comment: For example: if you read in lines out of a file

Answer (score 2):

```
map(dict,[[(1,2)]])
[{1: 2}]

map({},[[(1,2)]])
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```