# How to make PyCharm collapse/fold the dictionary constructor `dict()`?

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

I'm working in PyCharm, and to make my code more readable I'm using the [Folding Code Elements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-folding.html) (collapse/expand) feature.

Is there a way to **collapse a dictionary**, while still using the dict constructor `dict(key=value)`?

I'm aware that PyCharm allows code to be collapsed while using the dict literal `{key: value}` (see code example below).

I'd rather use the constructor for two reasons:

1. `Keys` are set without quotes `""`, therefore cleaner;
2. `Keys` are shown with a different color than `values`.

In case there is no way to collapse **dict constructor**, is there a good reason, other than [efficiency difference between dict declaration methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610606/is-there-a-difference-between-using-a-dict-literal-and-a-dict-constructor), why I'd use **dict literal** rather than **dict constructor**?

**Expanded code:**

```
# literal
thisdict_1 = {
    "brand": "Ford",
    "model": "Mustang",
    "year": 1964
}

# constructor
thisdict_2 = dict(
    brand="Ford",
    model="Mustang",
    year=1964
)
```

**Collapsed code:**

```
# literal
thisdict_1 = {...}

# constructor
thisdict_2 = dict(
    brand="Ford",
    model="Mustang",
    year=1964
)
```

Comment: A literal dict allows you to input keys as strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use special comment `<editor-fold desc="Description">`

```
a = dict(
    # <editor-fold desc="Description">
    z=4,
    d=77
    # </editor-fold>
)
```

Comment: Tks it worked!
Just found an alternative way with less charcters:

    `#region Description \n

    ... \n

    #endregion`

[Using code folding comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/code-folding.html#using_folding_comments)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to modify it like below as a hack with minimal typing:

```
a = {**dict(
    z=4,
    d=77
)}
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76329792/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

The normal way in python is

```
a = {'key': 'value', 'other key': 'other value'}
```