# What is the inverse function of zip in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I've used the `zip` function from the Numpy library to sort tuples and now I have a list containing all the tuples. I had since modified that list and now I would like to restore the tuples so I can use my data. How can I do this?

Answer (score 476, accepted):

```
lst1, lst2 = zip(*zipped_list)
```

should give you the unzipped list.

`*zipped_list` unpacks the zipped_list object. it then passes all the tuples from the zipped_list object to zip, which just packs them back up as they were when you passed them in.

so if:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

then `zipped_list = zip(a,b)` gives you:

```
[(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]
```

and `*zipped_list` gives you back

```
(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)
```

zipping that with `zip(*zipped_list)` gives you back the two collections:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: In other words `lambda x: zip(*x)` is self-inverse.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working: `l1 = [1,2,3]`, `l2 = [4,5,6]`; if I call `a,b = zip(*zip(l1,l2))`, then `a = (1,2,3) != l1 = [1,2,3]` (because [tuple != list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples))

Comment: @FoscoLoregian `a,b = map(list, zip(*zip(l1,l2)))`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473724/791430

Comment: Wouldn't it fail for Python version 3.6 and older  as soon as your list of zipped tuples contains more than 255 items ? (because of the maximum numbers of arguments that can be passed to a function) See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714475/what-is-a-maximum-number-of-arguments-in-a-python-function

Comment: No, because the limit of 255 doesn't apply when you expand args using *; see Chris Colbert's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714475/what-is-a-maximum-number-of-arguments-in-a-python-function

Comment: I might mention the fact that you can look at the `zip` function and notice that it is almost naturally the inverse of itself

Comment: having an unzip function would have been nice (even if just an alias of zip...)

Comment: This answer is not quite complete, if you start with two empty lists you will not get them back.

Comment: I thought that this method would work slowly but it actually worked better than all the other ways I imagined. Why is this so fast?

Comment: Took a while to wrap my head around, but obvious and mindblowingly elegant once I did. I had never thought of zip in that way