# Sort list B by the sort of list A?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have some list A with k elements, and list B with k elements as well. I want to sort list A, but I also want to permute list B in the same way.

For example

```
A = [2,3,1,4]
B = [5,6,7,8]
```

after sorting A:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [7,5,6,8]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting list based on values from another list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Comment: @Bolboa: Not quite a dupe since this question is asking to preserve both `A` and `B`. The other question doesn't address that.

Comment: @NPE I see, perhaps your right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
>>> A = [2,3,1,4]
>>> B = [5,6,7,8]
>>> A, B = zip(*sorted(zip(A, B)))
>>> list(A)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(B)
[7, 5, 6, 8]
```

In a nutshell:

- zip `A` and `B` into a list of pairs;
- sort the pairs;
- [unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635032/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-zip-in-python) back into `A` and `B`;
- convert tuples to lists.

If you like one-liners:

```
A, B = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(A, B))))
```

Comment: @MyNameIsKhan: `zip(*)` undoes the first `zip`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635032/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-zip-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
>>> A = [2,3,1,4]
>>> B = [5,6,7,8]
>>>
>>> AB = zip(A, B)
>>> AB.sort()
>>> A[:] = [t[0] for t in AB]
>>> B[:] = [t[1] for t in AB]
>>> A
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> B
[7, 5, 6, 8]
```

All we're doing here is "zipping" the list (i.e. in your example: `[(2, 5), (3, 6), (1, 7), (4, 8)]`) and sorting *that* list by the first element of each tuple. Then from this sorted list we retrieve the desired `A` and `B`.