# Join "colums" of list of lists into "rows" of list of lists

Tags: python

Suppose I have several lists of length n:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]
d = [-1, -2, -3]
```

I put those lists into a list:

```
x = [a, b, c]
```

Now I'd like to end up with the following list:

```
y = [[1, 4, 7, -1], [2, 5, 8, -2], [3, 6, 9, -3]]
```

What is a quick and pythonic way to do so? (To get from `x` to `y`.)

The entries could be anything, I use numbers just because they visualize good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple and pythonic way to "reverse-zip" a list in this way. Simple use the `zip` function and the unpacking operator `*`:

```
>>> y = zip(*x)
>>> list(y)
[(1, 4, 7, -1), (2, 5, 8, -2), (3, 6, 9, -3)]
```

For more information about what is going on, see [What is the inverse function of zip in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635032/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-zip-in-python)

If it is important that it be a list of lists, instead of a list of tuples, you can do the following:

```
>>> [list(i) for i in zip(*x)]
[[1, 4, 7, -1], [2, 5, 8, -2], [3, 6, 9, -3]]
```

Comment: Doesn't OP want a list of a list and not a list of tuple?

Comment: In most use cases I can think of it shouldn't really matter, but I added a code snippet for that as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one line of code:

```
[[z[i] for z in x] for i in range(len(x[0]))]
```

What it does is that to iterate over all indexes (`i`) and then iterate over all lists in `x` (`z`) and create a new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `zip`

```
>>> result = zip(a,b,c,d) # This gives ans as list of tuples [(1, 4, 7, -1), (2, 5, 8, -2), (3, 6, 9, -3)]
>>> result_list = [list(elem) for elem in result] #convert list of tuples to list of list
>>> result_list
[[1, 4, 7, -1], [2, 5, 8, -2], [3, 6, 9, -3]]
```