# Python list comprehensions that return multiple lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I don't know whether it is anyway possible in Python and that is the reason why I ask it here.

I have a Python function that returns a tuple:

```
def my_func(i):
    return i * 2, 'a' * i
```

This is just a dumb function that given a number `k`, it returns `k * 2` as is and another string is the letter 'a' concatenated `k` times.

I want now to form two lists, calling the function with `i = 0...9`, I want to create one list with all the first values and another one with the rest of them.

What I do with my current knowledge is:

**Option 1:** Run the same list comprehension two times, that is not very efficient:

```
first_vals = [my_func(i)[0] for i in range(10)]
second_vals = [my_func(i)[1] for i in range(10)]
```

**Option 2:** Avoiding list comprehensions:

```
first_vals = []
second_vals = []
for i in range(10):
    f, s = my_func(i)
    first_vals.append(f)
    second_vals.append(s)
```

**Option 3:** Use list comprehension to get a list of tuples and then two other list comprehension to copy the values. It is better than ***Option 1***, as here `my_func()` is only called once for each `i`:

```
ret = [my_func(i) for i in range(10)]
first_vals = [r[0] for r in ret]
second_vals = [r[1] for r in ret]
```

Is it possible to somehow use the list comprehension feature in order to return two lists in one command and one iteration, assigning each returned parameter into a different list?

Comment: a inverse zip function? : `lst1, lst2 = zip(*zipped_list)` - from the dupe answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635074/7505395

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the inverse function of zip in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635032/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-zip-in-python) - wich is marked ad dupe for [/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip) . SO-**Search** for the win ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner what you suggest is a post that helps those who already know what `zip()` is, and look for something very specific. You had known the answer and thus found a post that answers it as well, but I did not find a post with a similar *question*

Comment: Thank you anyway for the answer in the comments, it is very useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 4**: Use the inverse of `zip`:

```
first_vals, second_vals = zip(*[my_func(i) for i in range(10)])
```

As [Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson) pointed out in the comment this will lead to tuples for `first_vals` and `second_vals`. If you need them to be of type `list` you can, for example, apply a `map`:

```
first_vals, second_vals = map(list, zip(*[my_func(i) for i in range(10)]))
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner 1. You did not define `zipped_list`. 2. If your comment was supposed to be an answer, you should have posted it as one.

Comment: Note that this makes `first_vals` and `second_vals` into `tuple`s rather than `list`s, which may or may not be good enough for the OP.

Comment: That's great, thank you!!

Comment: @AgvaniaRekuva you are welcome! consider accepting it as the correct answer, if it was helpful.

Comment: @MarkDickinson you are right, I'll add your comment as clarification to the answer, if I may.

Comment: @PatrickArtner so you thought the question should not be answered, that's why you answered it with a comment? I do not understand that reasoning.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have gone through the intros and everything, but I'm fairly new to SO. It was my understanding that comments should not answer questions, but maybe I'm wrong about that. Was not my intention to step on you toes or anything!