# Unpack list of mixed tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of mixed tuples:

```
my_list = [("Adam",1985),("Karen",1990),("anna",1986)]
```

How to unpack it separately into two lists or tuples, one with strings and one with integers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the inverse function of zip in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635032/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-zip-in-python)

Comment: I believe its half a duplicate: I believe the question should be expanded to include the possibility of tuples both `(str, int)` and `(int, str)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If list schema is maintained as `(str, int)`

Using python's [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) you can easily unpack list of tuples, without any particular regard to types:

```
my_list = [("Adam",1985),("Karen",1990),("anna",1986)] 
names, years = zip(*my_list)
```

The unpacked lists are:

```
('Adam', 'Karen', 'anna'), (1985, 1990, 1986)
```

#### Notes on the `*` operator

The `*` operator is called [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), it passes the single elements of the list as argument. Suppose you have a list with 3 elements `my_list = [1, 2, 3]` ad a function with 3 parameters `def func(a, b, c)`: you can use `func(*my_list)` to call `func(my_list[0], my_list[1], ..., my_list[n])`.

### If list schema is shuffled

#### Solution using sorting, tuple by tuple

Using [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) we can first sort the tuples and then execute the zip:

```
import functools
key=functools.cmp_to_key(lambda x1, x2: 1 if isinstance(x2, str) else -1)
names, years = zip(*[sorted(t, key=key) for t in l])
```

This way the list is first sorted as:

```
[['Adam', 1985], ['Karen', 1990], ['anna', 1986]]
```

And afterwards running the zip we obtain the same result:

```
('Adam', 'Karen', 'anna'), (1985, 1990, 1986)
```

#### Solution using groupby

```
from itertools import chain, groupby
names, years = [
    list(v) for _, v in groupby(
        sorted(chain.from_iterable(my_list), key=lambda x: str(x)),
        lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
]
```

#### Solutions speed comparison on example list

Running timeit on the example list we get:

**Tuple sorting:**

```
%timeit zip(*[sorted(t, key=key) for t in my_list])
>>> 5.2 µs ± 157 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Groupby**

```
%timeit [list(v) for _, v in groupby(sorted(chain.from_iterable(my_list), key=lambda x: str(x)), lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
>>> 6.83 µs ± 358 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

#### Solutions speed comparison on large list

Running timeit on the a large list such as:

```
import random
n = 100000
my_list = []
for i in range(n):
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        my_list.append((i, "Karen"))
    else:
        my_list.append(("Karen", i))
```

**Tuple sorting:**

```
%timeit zip(*[sorted(t, key=key) for t in my_list])
>>> 166 ms ± 8.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Groupby**

```
%timeit [list(v) for _, v in groupby(sorted(chain.from_iterable(my_list), key=lambda x: str(x)), lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
>>> 149 ms ± 2.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### Conclusions

Even though on small list the first method seems to be the faster one, on larger list the groupby method appears faster.

Comment: what if `my_list = [(1, 'a'), ('b', 2)] ` ?

Comment: if i want to iterate over strings or integers,how to access each item. is there any  indexing here

Comment: Sure, suppose you want `"Adam"`: you go `names[0]`.

Comment: @ChihebNexus That will require looping, one sec.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti One way to do it: `from itertools import chain, groupby; a = [list(v) for _, v in groupby(sorted(chain.from_iterable(my_list), key=lambda x: str(x)), lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]; print(a)`

Comment: `zip(*mylist)` whats this part  * doing ?

Comment: It is called [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), it passes the single elements of the list as argument. Suppose you have a list with 3 elements `my_list = [1, 2, 3]` ad a function with 3 parameters `def func(a, b, c)`:  you can go `func(*my_list)` to call `func(my_list[0], my_list[1], ..., my_list[n])`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip`

```
>>> years, names = zip(*(sorted(t, key=lambda x: str(type(x))) for t in my_list))
>>> years
(1985, 1990, 1986)
>>> names
('Adam', 'Karen', 'anna')
>>>
```

Or using `dict`

```
>>> d = dict(sorted(t, key=lambda x: str(type(x))) for t in my_list)
>>> years = tuple(d.keys())
>>> names = tuple(d.values())
>>> 
>>> years
(1985, 1990, 1986)
>>> names
('Adam', 'Karen', 'anna')
>>>
```

Comment: @Karamzov `sorted(t, key=lambda x: str(type(x))) for t in my_list)` would return a list of tuples in ordered form, that is in a form where years will always come first and the names would come next. You can skip this step if your list is already in order

Comment: why :  `key=lambda x` not  `lamda x`  .. ?

Comment: There is nothing called `lamda` in python. `lambda` is the correct terminology

Comment: : key=lambda x not lambda x .. ?

Comment: If you dont specify `key=` to sorted method, it will complain `TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function` as it expects only keyword arguments

Answer (score 1):

you can convert it into dictionary and work as normal

```
dict([("Adam",1985),("Karen",1990),("anna",1986)])
```

> {'Adam': 1985, 'Karen': 1990, 'anna': 1986}

Comment: converting dictionary is easy method , how to convert and iterate here