# Iterate a Python zip list and save the result in two different lists

Tags: python, list

My program has two lists of numbers. What I want to do is to iterate over the zip list obtained doing `zip()`, apply two different functions on the two intermediate variables and save the first result (apply `compute_add()`) in one list and the second (apply `compute_sub()`) in another. I can do it iterating two times on the zip list but I'm wondering if there is a way to do so in one shot. 
 Here is my code, of course is not running.

```
def compute_add(_x, _y):
    return _x * _y + 10


def compute_sub(_x, _y):
    return _x * _y - 10


list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

res1, res2 = [compute_add(x, y), compute_sub(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Only way to do it with a single for loop is to not use a list comprehension since you're trying to comprehend two lists, not one

Comment: What’s wrong with your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the sums in one list and the differences in another, there isn't a straightforward way to do that with a list comprehension.  You could collect the pairs in a tuple and then split back up into two lists:

```
tup = [(compute_add(x, y), compute_sub(x, y)) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
res1 = [t[0] for t in tup]
res2 = [t[1] for t in tup]
```

With just a single loop over the zip, I would simply do

```
res1 = []
res2 = []
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    res1.append(compute_add(x,y))
    res2.append(compute_sub(x,y))
```

If the functions are genuinely this simple, of course, you can factor out the multiplication:

```
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    mul = x * y
    res1.append(mul + 10)
    res2.append(mul - 10)
```

For what it's worth, [What is the inverse function of zip in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635032/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-zip-in-python) has a nice answer to "how can I do the reverse of `zip()`" but it effectively traverses the list two times as well.

Answer (score 1):

> **Method 1:** using *list-comprehensions*

```
def compute_add(_x, _y):
    return _x * _y + 10
def compute_sub(_x, _y):
    return _x * _y - 10

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
res1 = [compute_add(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
res2 = [compute_sub(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]

print(res1) # [20, 50, 100, 170, 260]
print(res2) # [0, 30, 80, 150, 240]
```

> **Method 2:** using *for loop*

You can simply iterate over the zip list obtained and apply directly your defined functions. See the above code.

```
def compute_add(_x, _y):
    return _x * _y + 10
def compute_sub(_x, _y):
    return _x * _y - 10

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
res1 = []
res2 = []
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    res1.append(compute_add(x, y))
    res2.append(compute_sub(x, y))

print(res1) # [20, 50, 100, 170, 260]
print(res2) # [0, 30, 80, 150, 240]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the results to two list during the iteration

```
res1 = []
res2 = []
[[res1.append(compute_add(x, y)), res2.append(compute_sub(x, y))] for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]

print(res1, res2) # [20, 50, 100, 170, 260] [0, 30, 80, 150, 240]
```

Comment: This is a bit of an abuse of list comprehensions, though; you are using the comprehension for side effects, and throwing away the thing it actually *does.*

Answer (score 1):

Try using `zip`:

```
res1, res2 = zip(*[(compute_add(x, y), compute_sub(x, y)) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the code like this

```
res1, res2 = [[compute_add(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)], [compute_sub(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]]
```