# sort bars in ascending order without involving dataFrames

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-science, data-analysis

I have two lists and I am plotting a graph using matplotlib. Currently, the bars are organized in the way the lists are written. I want to set them in an ascending/descending order automatically. How can I do so?

```
industries = ['Manufacturing', 'Food', 'Eco']
counts = [12,78,1]

plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
bars = plt.bar(industries, counts, width=0.2, bottom=None, align='center', data=None)
plt.xlim(-0.9, len(industries) - 1 + 0.9)
for i in range(len(counts)):
    percentage = ((counts[i]/(total))*100)
    plt.annotate(percentage, xy=(industries[i], counts[i] + 10), ha='center')
plt.show()
```

Edit:

I realized that the bars are built on the basis of alphabetical order. Even if the data is sorted. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve all your bar plotting questions now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The two lists need to be combined with `zip` and then sorted on the counts.
- Iterate through the `list` of `tuples` to add the bars, in sorted order in `reverse` order, with the annotation.

```py
industries = ['Manufacturing', 'Food', 'Eco']
counts = [12, 78, 1]
tot = sum(counts)

# combine the two lists with zip and then reverse sort them
data = sorted(zip(industries, counts), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
for (i, c) in data:  # unpack and plot each tuple in sorted order
    bars = plt.bar(i, c, width=0.2, bottom=None, align='center', data=None, color='g')
    plt.annotate(f'{(c/tot)*100:0.02f}%\n', xy=(i, c), va='center', ha='center')
plt.xlim(-0.9, len(industries) - 1 + 0.9)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First sort the lists as you need them by `zip`ing them,  sort, and then "[unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635074/1011724)" them:

```
industries = ['Manufacturing', 'Food', 'Eco']
counts = [12,78,1]

sorted_counts, sorted_industries = zip(*sorted(zip(counts, industries), reverse=True))
```

Or set `reversed=False` for ascending.

Then plot like this

```py
x_locations = range(len(industries))
plt.bar(x_locations, sorted_counts, , tick_label=sorted_industries, ...)
```

If you look at the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) you'll see the first parameter is not the bar labels but there x-coordinates. The simplest way to get them evenly spaced is to use `range`. Then you can change the tick lables using the `tick_labels` argument.

Just to note, when I try it using `plt.bar(sorted_industries, sorted_counts)`, it is plotting them in the expected order, not alphabetical. What version of matplotlib are you trying this with?

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense too but sorting the list isn't the problem. Matplotlib automatically arranges everything in an alphabetical order even when the lists are sorted

Comment: oh I see - yeah you should use `range(len(industries))` as the x-values, I'll update

Comment: @a125 see my edit on how to plot it in the correct order