# Can I combine 2 list comprehensions in a single line?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here's part of my Python code:

```
pstat1 = [plotvex(alpha,beta,j)[0] for j in range(5)]
ptset1 = [plotvex(alpha,beta,j)[1] for j in range(5)]
```

where `plotvex` is a function that returns 2 items. I want to generate two lists `pstat1` and `ptset1` using list comprehension, but I wonder is there a way I don't need to call the function twice? Thanks:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635032/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-zip-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `plotvex()` returns a 2-tuple exactly*, this should work:

```
pstat1, ptset1 = zip(*[plotvex(alpha, beta, j) for j in range(5)])
```

`zip(*iterable_of_iterables)` is a common idiom to 'rotate' a list of lists from being vertical to being horizontal. So instead of a list of 2-tuples, `[plotvex(alpha, beta, j) for j in range(5)]` will become two lists of singles, one list from each half of the tuples.

`*` here is the argument-unpacking operator.

---

*if it returns more than a 2-tuple, then just do `plotvex(alpha, beta, j)[:2]` instead to take the first two elements

Comment: If `plotvex` doesn't return a 2-tuple, another solution would be to do `pstat1, ptset1, *_ = zip(*[plotvex(alpha, beta, j) for j in range(5)])`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a way I can directly return `pstat1` and `ptset1` as list?

Comment: @ZR- if you need to you can add another comprehension on the outside to convert tuple to list - `[list(tup) for tup in zip(...)]`, and it shouldn't hurt anything

Answer (score 7):

You are quite right that you don't want to call the `plotvex()` function twice for each set of parameters.

So, just call it once and then generate `pstat1` and `pstat2` later:

```py
pv = [plotvex(alpha,beta,j) for j in range(5)]
pstat1 = [item[0] for item in pv]
ptset1 = [item[1] for item in pv]
```