# Split a list into two different lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist

Can someone help me split a list into two

Example of a list:

```
[[[9.0, 16.0], [11.0, 15.0], [12.0, 16.0], [14.0, 13.0]], [[22.0, 13.0], [23.0, 14.0]]]
```

Output:

```
A=[9.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, 22.0, 23.0]
B=[16.0, 15.0, 16.0, 13.0, 13.0, 14.0]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the inverse function of zip in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635032/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-zip-in-python)

Comment: `A, B = list(zip(*values))`

Comment: @PeterWood first he needs to use `values = chain.from_iterable(values)` then use `zip`

Comment: @user1740577 ah, I didn't notice the nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chain` then split to two `list` like below:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst = [[[9.0, 16.0], [11.0, 15.0], [12.0, 16.0], [14.0, 13.0]], [[22.0, 13.0], [23.0, 14.0]]]

>>> lst = list(chain.from_iterable(lst))
>>> lst
[[9.0, 16.0],
 [11.0, 15.0],
 [12.0, 16.0],
 [14.0, 13.0],
 [22.0, 13.0],
 [23.0, 14.0]]
    
>>> [l[0] for l in lst]
[9.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, 22.0, 23.0]


>>> [l[1] for l in lst]
[16.0, 15.0, 16.0, 13.0, 13.0, 14.0]
```

By thanks @PeterWood you can use `zip` like below:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst = [[[9.0, 16.0], [11.0, 15.0], [12.0, 16.0], [14.0, 13.0]], [[22.0, 13.0], [23.0, 14.0]]]
>>> lst = chain.from_iterable(lst)

>>> A, B = list(zip(*lst))
>>> list(A)
[9.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, 22.0, 23.0]

>>> list(B)
[16.0, 15.0, 16.0, 13.0, 13.0, 14.0]
```

Comment: `zip` is easier.