# Any way to bypass namedtuple 255 arguments limitation?

Tags: python, namedtuple

I'm using a namedtuple to hold sets of strings and their corresponding values.
I'm not using a dictionary, because I want the strings accessible as attributes.

Here's my code:

```
from collections import namedtuple


# Shortened for readability :-)
strings = namedtuple("strings", ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', ..., 'a400'])
my_strings = strings(value0, value1, value2, ..., value400)
```

Ideally, once `my_strings` is initialized, I should be able to do this:

```
print(my_strings.a1)
```

and get `value1` printed back.

**However**, I get the following error instead:

```
strings(value0, value1, value2, ...value400)

   ^SyntaxError: more than 255 arguments
```

It seems python functions (including namedtuple's **init**()), do not accept more than 255 arguments when called. 
Is there any way to bypass this issue and have named tuples with more than 255 items? Why is there a 255 arguments limit anyway?

Comment: Are you actually typing out 401 strings and 401 names?  That's not a great idea.

Comment: @DSM - no I wrote a Python script that does that :-)

Comment: complete stack trace?

Comment: @valorien: that's a sign your approach has gone off the rails, I'm afraid. :^)

Comment: @hus787, the SyntaxError exception is all I got.

Comment: Nope. You definitely would have got a lot more then that. http://pastebin.com/G4zRFxzN

Comment: related -->  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36345375/674039

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a limit to CPython function definitions; in versions before Python 3.7, you cannot specify more than 255 explicit arguments to a callable. This applies to any function definition, not just named tuples.

Note that this limit has been lifted in Python 3.7 and newer, where the new limit is `sys.maxint`. See [What is a maximum number of arguments in a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714475/what-is-a-maximum-number-of-arguments-in-a-python-function/48051450#48051450)

It is the generated code for the class that is hitting this limit. You cannot define a function with more than 255 arguments; the `__new__` class method of the resulting class is thus not achievable in the CPython implementation.

You'll have to ask yourself, however, if you really should be using a different structure instead. It looks like you have a list-like piece of data to me; 400 numbered names is a sure sign of your [data bleeding into your names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

You can work around this by creating your own subclass, manually:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import OrderedDict

class strings(tuple):
    __slots__ = ()
    _fields = tuple('a{}'.format(i) for i in range(400))
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        req = len(cls._fields)
        if len(args) + len(kwargs) > req:
            raise TypeError(
                '__new__() takes {} positional arguments but {} were given'.format(
                    req, len(args) + len(kwargs)))
        if kwargs.keys() > set(cls._fields):
            raise TypeError(
                '__new__() got an unexpected keyword argument {!r}'.format(
                    (kwargs.keys() - set(cls._fields)).pop()))
        missing = req - len(args)
        if kwargs.keys() & set(cls._fields[:-missing]):
            raise TypeError(
                '__new__() got multiple values for argument {!r}'.format(
                    (kwargs.keys() & set(cls._fields[:-missing])).pop()))
        try:
            for field in cls._fields[-missing:]:
                args += (kwargs[field],)
                missing -= 1
        except KeyError:
            pass
        if len(args) < req:
            raise TypeError('__new__() missing {} positional argument{}: {}'.format(
                missing, 's' if missing > 1 else '',
                ' and '.join(filter(None, [', '.join(map(repr, cls._fields[-missing:-1])), repr(cls._fields[-1])]))))
        return tuple.__new__(cls, args)

    @classmethod
    def _make(cls, iterable, new=tuple.__new__, len=len):
        'Make a new strings object from a sequence or iterable'
        result = new(cls, iterable)
        if len(result) != len(cls._fields):
            raise TypeError('Expected %d arguments, got %d' % (len(cls._fields), len(result)))
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        'Return a nicely formatted representation string'
        format = '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join('{}=%r'.format(n) for n in self._fields))
        return format % self

    def _asdict(self):
        'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values'
        return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))

    __dict__ = property(_asdict)

    def _replace(self, **kwds):
        'Return a new strings object replacing specified fields with new values'
        result = self._make(map(kwds.pop, self._fields, self))
        if kwds:
            raise ValueError('Got unexpected field names: %r' % list(kwds))
        return result

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        'Return self as a plain tuple.  Used by copy and pickle.'
        return tuple(self)

    def __getstate__(self):
        'Exclude the OrderedDict from pickling'
        return None

for i, name in enumerate(strings._fields):
    setattr(strings, name, 
            property(itemgetter(i), doc='Alias for field number {}'.format(i)))
```

This version of the named tuple avoids the long argument lists altogether, but otherwise behaves exactly like the original. The somewhat verbose `__new__` method is not strictly needed but does closely emulate the original behaviour when arguments are incomplete. Note the construction of the `_fields` attribute; replace this with your own to name your tuple fields.

Pass in a generator expression to set your arguments:

```
s = strings(i for i in range(400))
```

or if you have a list of values:

```
s = strings(iter(list_of_values))
```

Either technique bypasses the limits on function signatures and function call argument counts.

Demo:

```
>>> s = strings(i for i in range(400))
>>> s
strings(a0=0, a1=1, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4, a5=5, a6=6, a7=7, a8=8, a9=9, a10=10, a11=11, a12=12, a13=13, a14=14, a15=15, a16=16, a17=17, a18=18, a19=19, a20=20, a21=21, a22=22, a23=23, a24=24, a25=25, a26=26, a27=27, a28=28, a29=29, a30=30, a31=31, a32=32, a33=33, a34=34, a35=35, a36=36, a37=37, a38=38, a39=39, a40=40, a41=41, a42=42, a43=43, a44=44, a45=45, a46=46, a47=47, a48=48, a49=49, a50=50, a51=51, a52=52, a53=53, a54=54, a55=55, a56=56, a57=57, a58=58, a59=59, a60=60, a61=61, a62=62, a63=63, a64=64, a65=65, a66=66, a67=67, a68=68, a69=69, a70=70, a71=71, a72=72, a73=73, a74=74, a75=75, a76=76, a77=77, a78=78, a79=79, a80=80, a81=81, a82=82, a83=83, a84=84, a85=85, a86=86, a87=87, a88=88, a89=89, a90=90, a91=91, a92=92, a93=93, a94=94, a95=95, a96=96, a97=97, a98=98, a99=99, a100=100, a101=101, a102=102, a103=103, a104=104, a105=105, a106=106, a107=107, a108=108, a109=109, a110=110, a111=111, a112=112, a113=113, a114=114, a115=115, a116=116, a117=117, a118=118, a119=119, a120=120, a121=121, a122=122, a123=123, a124=124, a125=125, a126=126, a127=127, a128=128, a129=129, a130=130, a131=131, a132=132, a133=133, a134=134, a135=135, a136=136, a137=137, a138=138, a139=139, a140=140, a141=141, a142=142, a143=143, a144=144, a145=145, a146=146, a147=147, a148=148, a149=149, a150=150, a151=151, a152=152, a153=153, a154=154, a155=155, a156=156, a157=157, a158=158, a159=159, a160=160, a161=161, a162=162, a163=163, a164=164, a165=165, a166=166, a167=167, a168=168, a169=169, a170=170, a171=171, a172=172, a173=173, a174=174, a175=175, a176=176, a177=177, a178=178, a179=179, a180=180, a181=181, a182=182, a183=183, a184=184, a185=185, a186=186, a187=187, a188=188, a189=189, a190=190, a191=191, a192=192, a193=193, a194=194, a195=195, a196=196, a197=197, a198=198, a199=199, a200=200, a201=201, a202=202, a203=203, a204=204, a205=205, a206=206, a207=207, a208=208, a209=209, a210=210, a211=211, a212=212, a213=213, a214=214, a215=215, a216=216, a217=217, a218=218, a219=219, a220=220, a221=221, a222=222, a223=223, a224=224, a225=225, a226=226, a227=227, a228=228, a229=229, a230=230, a231=231, a232=232, a233=233, a234=234, a235=235, a236=236, a237=237, a238=238, a239=239, a240=240, a241=241, a242=242, a243=243, a244=244, a245=245, a246=246, a247=247, a248=248, a249=249, a250=250, a251=251, a252=252, a253=253, a254=254, a255=255, a256=256, a257=257, a258=258, a259=259, a260=260, a261=261, a262=262, a263=263, a264=264, a265=265, a266=266, a267=267, a268=268, a269=269, a270=270, a271=271, a272=272, a273=273, a274=274, a275=275, a276=276, a277=277, a278=278, a279=279, a280=280, a281=281, a282=282, a283=283, a284=284, a285=285, a286=286, a287=287, a288=288, a289=289, a290=290, a291=291, a292=292, a293=293, a294=294, a295=295, a296=296, a297=297, a298=298, a299=299, a300=300, a301=301, a302=302, a303=303, a304=304, a305=305, a306=306, a307=307, a308=308, a309=309, a310=310, a311=311, a312=312, a313=313, a314=314, a315=315, a316=316, a317=317, a318=318, a319=319, a320=320, a321=321, a322=322, a323=323, a324=324, a325=325, a326=326, a327=327, a328=328, a329=329, a330=330, a331=331, a332=332, a333=333, a334=334, a335=335, a336=336, a337=337, a338=338, a339=339, a340=340, a341=341, a342=342, a343=343, a344=344, a345=345, a346=346, a347=347, a348=348, a349=349, a350=350, a351=351, a352=352, a353=353, a354=354, a355=355, a356=356, a357=357, a358=358, a359=359, a360=360, a361=361, a362=362, a363=363, a364=364, a365=365, a366=366, a367=367, a368=368, a369=369, a370=370, a371=371, a372=372, a373=373, a374=374, a375=375, a376=376, a377=377, a378=378, a379=379, a380=380, a381=381, a382=382, a383=383, a384=384, a385=385, a386=386, a387=387, a388=388, a389=389, a390=390, a391=391, a392=392, a393=393, a394=394, a395=395, a396=396, a397=397, a398=398, a399=399)
>>> s.a391
391
```

Comment: I tried both the generator and the *(iterable) solution. Same error I'm afraid. I've read Ned's post, and I'm pretty sure that's not the case here. I just have a lot of unique names that would be easier to handle with a namedtuple.

Comment: @valorien: I tested this with a simple, regular tuple first; the generator expression works for that case. I am trying to build a  `namedtuple` class but it won't even work because of the argument limit (the `__new__` method signature has more than 255 arguments, so this fails).

Comment: @Martin: Exactly. That's the crux of my issue.

Answer (score 2):

`namedtuple` out of the box doesn't support what you are trying to do.

So the following might achieve the goal, which might change from `400` to `450` arguments, or lesser and saner.

```
def customtuple(*keys):
        class string:
            _keys = keys 
            _dict = {}
            def __init__(self, *args):
                args = list(args)
                if len(args) != len(self._keys):
                    raise Exception("No go forward")

                for key in range(len(args)):
                    self._dict[self._keys[key]] = args[key]

            def __setattr__(self, *args):
                raise BaseException("Not allowed")

            def __getattr__(self, arg):
                try:
                    return self._dict[arg]
                except:
                    raise BaseException("Name not defined")

            def __repr__(self):
                return ("string(%s)"
                        %(", ".join(["%s=%r"
                                     %(self._keys[key],
                                       self._dict[self._keys[key]])
                                     for key in range(len(self._dict))])))

        return string
>>> strings = customtuple(*['a'+str(x) for x in range(1, 401)])
>>> s = strings(*['a'+str(x) for x in range(2, 402)])
>>> s.a1
'a2'
>>> s.a1 = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hus787/p.py", line 15, in __setattr__
    def __setattr__(self, *args):
BaseException: Not allowed
```

[For more light on the subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/714475/1309352)

Comment: Doesn't work. the __init__() of namedtuple still gets more than 255 arguments this way (tested on Python 3.3).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of a replacement for `namedtuple` that supports more than 255 arguments.  The idea was not to be functionally equivalent but rather to improve on some aspects (in my opinion).  This is for **Python 3.4+** only:

```
class SequenceAttrReader(object):
    """ Class to function similar to collections.namedtuple but allowing more than 255 keys.
        Initialize with attribute string (space separated), then load in data via a sequence, then access the list keys as properties

        i.e.

        csv_line = SequenceAttrReader('a b c')
        csv_line = csv_line.load([1, 2, 3])

        print(csv_line.b)

        >> 2
    """

    _attr_string = None
    _attr_list = []
    _data_list = []

    def __init__(self, attr_string):
        if not attr_string:
            raise AttributeError('SequenceAttrReader not properly initialized, please use a non-empty string')

        self._attr_string = attr_string
        self._attr_list = attr_string.split(' ')

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if not self._attr_string or not self._attr_list or not self._data_list:
            raise AttributeError('SequenceAttrReader not properly initialized or loaded')

        try:
            index = self._attr_list.index(name)
        except ValueError:
            raise AttributeError("'{name}'' not in attribute string".format(name=name)) from None

        try:
            value = self._data_list[index]
        except IndexError:
            raise AttributeError("No attribute named '{name}'' in".format(name=name)) from None

        return value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._data_list)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'SequenceAttrReader("{attr_string}")'.format(attr_string=self._attr_string)

    def load_data(self, data_list):
        if not self._attr_list:
            raise AttributeError('SequenceAttrReader not properly initialized')

        if not data_list:
            raise AttributeError('SequenceAttrReader needs to load a non-empty sequence')

        self._data_list = data_list
```

This is probably not the most efficient way if you are doing a lot of individual lookups, converting it internally to a `dict` may be better.  I'll work on an optimized version once I have more time or at least see what the performance difference is.