# Limitations to .format in python

Tags: python

So I am fairly new to Python as I am sure will become apparent.
Anyways, is there a limit to the number of arguments I can pass when using .format?
I have a list of 8000 numbers that need to replace existing numbers in a long input in various places in the input.  At the moment, I am  planning on doing this:

```
text = """ very long input with many {0}..{1}..{8000} in various places """
file = open('new_input', 'w')
file.write(text.format(x,x1,x2,....x8000))
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Because with this exact code, it looks like you want to manually write something 8000 times. There will most definitely be a much easier way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Whether or not `format` can do this (pretty sure it can), this doesn't look like a job for `format`. Also, do you seriously have 8000 numbered variables?

Comment: There is no limit, but having to do this is highly inadvisable simply because it'll be very ugly to read and maintain. It is much better to write line by line to your file rather than manually introduce 8000 items into your string and write the whole thing at once.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I think I can get it now. And yes, 8000ish. I have 21 radial nodes with 24 axial nodes for each and I am extracting 3 different temperatrure measurements at each node, and in order to properly adjust the reactor code, I need to have 4 to 6 more variable for each node depending on the temperature value.  And it could be worse!
Thanks again, for the comments!

Comment: You should use a data structure object like a list or a dict instead of named variables. That's the purpose of data structures.

Answer (score 5):

[As wim notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36345308/364696), you could do it with argument unpacking, but if you actually passed them positionally as individual named arguments, it wouldn't work; there is a limit of 255 explicitly provided individual arguments.

Demonstration:

```
>>> globals().update(('x{}'.format(i), i) for i in range(8000))
>>> codestr = '("{{}}"*8000).format({})'.format(', '.join('x{}'.format(i) for i in range(8000)))
>>> eval(codestr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: more than 255 arguments
```

The limit is due to how the `CALL_FUNCTION` opcode is defined; it's encoded as a single byte indicating the opcode, then one byte for the number of positional arguments, and one for the number of keyword arguments. While in theory it could handle up to 510 total arguments, they actually impose a combined limit of 255 arguments, presumably for consistency. So you can't actually call a function with more than 255 total arguments without involving `*` or `**` unpacking.

This is all technically an implementation detail BTW; there is no language requirement that it work this way, so it could change in a future release of CPython (the reference interpreter) and behave differently in any other interpreter (most of which don't produce or use CPython bytecode anyway) right now.

Comment: Interesting!  You might want to double-check the details of the bytes / opcode you've mentioned.  I poked it a bit and could never get 510 total arguments working (attempted python v3.5.0, python v2.7.5, and pypy v2.2.1).  My test harness is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wimglenn/scratch/master/str_nargs.py).

Comment: @wim: I investigated further; looks like even though the instruction encoding would allow 255 of each, they limited the cumulative number of arguments to 255 total, presumably either for implementation simplicity or consistency (it would be weird if you could pass 300 arguments split evenly between positional and keyword, but not 300 positionally).

Comment: [Note:  the limit of 255 arguments is lifted in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#other-language-changes)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any hard limit and 8000 is not that big anyway, I think it should not be any problem.

Example with positional templating:

```
>>> text = "{} "*8000
>>> text = text.format(*range(8000))
>>> '{' in text
False
>>> text[:50]
'0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 '
>>> text[-50:]
'7990 7991 7992 7993 7994 7995 7996 7997 7998 7999 '
```

Example with name templating:

```
>>> s = ' '.join(['{{x{}}}'.format(i) for i in range(8000)])
>>> d = {'x{}'.format(i):i for i in range(8000)}
>>> s[:25] + '...' + s[-24:]
'{x0} {x1} {x2} {x3} {x4} ... {x7997} {x7998} {x7999}'
>>> s = s.format(**d)
>>> s[:25] + '...' + s[-24:]
'0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11...7995 7996 7997 7998 7999'
```