# How many parameters can a function have in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

The title says it all but can a Python function have as many parameters as needed? There is no end limit?

Thank you in advance. Have a nice day!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a maximum number of arguments in a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714475/what-is-a-maximum-number-of-arguments-in-a-python-function)

Comment: How many can it have, or how many should it have?